# edge how to enable resizeable about the popup window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I used window.showModalDialog(url,windowName,status)to open a popup window on IE and the popup window can't resizeable.

The showModalDialog doesn't work on Edge ,so I use window.open(url,windowName,status) to replace it on Edge,but the resizeable=no option of window.open(url,windowName,"resizeable=no") does't work on Edge.

How can I enable my popup window resizeable with window.open() on Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showModalDialog()` method is obsolete. For `window.open()`, IE supports disabling the resizing, but other browsers no longer support it. You can check the [Parameter Values](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) of this link.

As a workaround, you can use [jQuery EasyUI Dialog](https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/dialog.php). You can refer to the example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dd').dialog({
    title: 'My Dialog',
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    closed: false,
    cache: false,
    href: 'http://www.google.com',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false //It can define whether the dialog box can be resized.
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dd">Dialog Content.</div>
```